# inject entitymanager using spring+jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, entitymanager

How to inject EntityManager object using spring+JPA

I am using spring-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javapapers.spring.mvc" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cnsi.dao.Impl" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/spitterPU" 
        /> -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.86.24.7:1521:wahipaaD" />
        <property name="username" value="mddemo" />
        <property name="password" value="mddemo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/ spring-persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="personPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" /> -->
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean class="com.cnsi.dao.Impl.JpaUserDao" id="jpaUserDao">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> -->

</beans>
```

And my dao is, inject EntityManager

```
package com.cnsi.dao.Impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.cnsi.dao.UserDao;
import com.cnsi.modal.User;

@Repository
public class JpaUserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    @Override
    public void add(User u) {
        em.persist(u);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(User u) {
        em.merge(u);

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {

        em.remove(getInterfaceId(id));

    }

    @Override
    public User getInterfaceId(int id) {

        return (User) em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllInterface() {

        return em.createQuery("from user").getResultList();
    }

}
```

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="personPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <class>com.cnsi.modal.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaVendorAdapter()Lorg/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaVendorAdapter;
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:240)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:232)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
```

Comment: See if [this read](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) helps.

Comment: Your `JpaUserDaoImpl` is also flawed. You shouldn't retrieve an `EntityManager` like that. Either retrieve it in the method or inject the `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext` on a field in the dao.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

That's how you inject entity manager in your controller.